# FlatButton.icon with Overflowing Text in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to make a `FlatButton` with overflowing `Text`. To show the widget boxes, I placed `Container`s around some of the widgets.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.lime,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: FlatButton.icon(
                label: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text('Short Text'),
                ),
                icon: Icon(Icons.done),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.orange,
              child: FlatButton.icon(
                label: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text('Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Text'),
                ),
                icon: Icon(Icons.done),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: Result of above code]

To solve the overflow error and add ellipsis at the end of overflowing `Text`s, I've read the [`FlatButton.icon` source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/fabf4e3d0d311181178d2c601d29a2f739ea543a/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/flat_button.dart#L270), which wrap the `Text` widget into a `Row`:

```
child: Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
      icon,
      const SizedBox(width: 8.0),
      label,
    ],
),
```

So, I wrap the "Long Text" Widget into a `Flexible` widget with `flexFit` set to `loose`, and set the `overflow` property of the `Text` widgets to `ellipsis`:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.lime,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: FlatButton.icon(
                label: Flexible(
                  fit: FlexFit.loose,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Text(
                      'Short Text',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                icon: Icon(Icons.done),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.orange,
              child: FlatButton.icon(
                label: Flexible(
                  fit: FlexFit.loose,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text(
                      'Long Long Long Long Looong Loooooooooooong',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                icon: Icon(Icons.done),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: Result of above code]

But in the "Long Text" widget, since some text has already been turned into ellipsis, I would like to reduce the width of the `Text` more. Specifically, I don't want the red space after the "...". Below is the ideal layout:
[image: Ideal result]

Any way to achieve this?

EDIT: To clarify, the text of the `FlatButton` depends on user content, so the layout needs to be suitable for all text and all device sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Define a maxWidth property like this :

```dart
Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  constraints: BoxConstraints(
    maxWidth: 300 // set a correct maxWidth
  )
  child: Text(
    'Long Long Long Long Looong Loooooooooooong',
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  ),
)
```

You can use :

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
```

to get the width of the screen of your phone/tablet.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve the problem... [Code](https://pastebin.com/jwptMG1D), [Result](https://imgur.com/a/o39uzpH)

Comment: Use 100 instead of 50. It works really fine for me.

Comment: The text of the `FlatButton`s is controlled by the user, so a hard-coded value isn’t going to work for every text.

Comment: Then use relative (80% of width screen for example).

Comment: Btw, you are setting the maximum width the container can be, not the current width.
If you use the MediaQuery.of(context) then it is relative to the screen. If the text is larger than the container maximum width, it will just add the ellipsis. I don't see the issue right there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the padding property of the `Container` you have holding the `Text` widget to reduce the max size it will take:

```
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 80, right: 80),
  color: Colors.red,
  child: Text('Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Text',
    softWrap: false,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution adds space around the `Text` widgets, but I want to minimize the width of the `Text` widget caused by the ellipsis. Here is the result of your solution: https://i.imgur.com/HoTJWOp.png

Comment: Do you mean between the text and the "..." or just around? If just around then swap the `padding` to `margin`.

Comment: I want to remove the red space after the "...". To clarify, the text of both `FlatButton`s depends on user input, so the solution needs to apply to both `FlatButtons`. Adding margin or padding takes up space, which I don't prefer. https://i.imgur.com/OzqLRNr.png

Comment: That space that you have after the "..." is being made by you, not the `TextOverflow.ellipsis`.